# Is $f(x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\dots,x \in \Bbb{R}$ continuos?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Problem** Is $f$ continuous? Where,  $f(x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\dots,x \in \Bbb{R}$.

**My Solution.** Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n},x \in \Bbb{R}$. I've checked the convergency of the series $\sum f_n$:

Now $S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}f_n(x)=x^2[1+\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n}}]=(1+x^2)[1-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}],x \in \Bbb{R}$

Now for any $x \in \Bbb{R}, \lim_{n\to \infty} S_n(x)=1+x^2(=g(x),say)$

Therefore $S_n \to g$ pointwise on $\Bbb{R}$. Hence $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$.

Can I say now that $f$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$ as $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$?

But as we can see $S_n$ is not uniformly convergent to $g$ .....Since $\|S_n-g\|_{\infty}\ge 1$...!!!

I am getting confused here....$f$ is pointwise **equal** to a continuous function ON THE OTHER HAND the series $\sum f_n$ is not uniformly convergent on $\Bbb{R}$...!!!

How to decide whether $f$ is continuous or not....?? Please tell me where I made a mistake..Thank you.

Comment: No. $f(0) = 0 \neq 1+0^2 = g(0)$, hence not continuous.

Comment: Yes u r right ...?? But is there any calculation mistake in my answer .....especially in proving pointwise converent

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396373/how-to-show-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracx21x2n-is-uniformly-conv?rq=1)

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh Yes, there is a mistake. When you say implicitly that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x^{2})^{-n} = 0$, you assume that $1/(1+x^{2}) < 1$. This is not true when $x=0$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood...right....thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, $f(0) \neq g( 0)$, since the formula of geometric series is not applicable when $x = 0$. Thus 
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & x=0\\
g(x), & \text {else}
\end{cases}. 
$$